# How to “template” a registry class that uses __new__ as a factory?

Tags: python, metaclass

I wrote a class `BaseRegistry` that uses a classmethod as a decorator to register other classes with a string name in a class attribute dictionary `registered`.

This dictionary is used to return the class associated to the string name given to its `__new__` method.

This works quite well but now, I would like to create several Registries of this kind without duplicating code. Of course, if I inherit from `BaseRegistry`, the dictionary is shared between all subclasses which is not what I want.

I can not figure out how to achieve this “templating”.

Below a code example:

```py
class BaseRegistry:
    registered = {}

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, name):
        def decorator(function):
            cls.registered[name] = function
            return function

        return decorator

    def __new__(cls, name):
        return cls.registered[name]


class RegistryOne(BaseRegistry):
    pass


class RegistryTwo(BaseRegistry):
    pass


@RegistryOne.add("the_one")
class Example1:
    def __init__(self, scale_factor=1):
        self.scale_factor = scale_factor


@RegistryOne.add("the_two")
class Example2:
    def __init__(self, scale_factor=2):
        self.scale_factor = scale_factor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_one = RegistryOne("the_one")()
    print(f"{the_one.scale_factor=}")

    assert RegistryOne.registered != RegistryTwo.registered
```

Of course, I would like to find a solution to make this code works but I am also opened to any alternative implementation of `BaseRegistry` that would achieve the same goal.

EDIT:

With this implementation, Pylint complains about the line:

```py
the_one = RegistryOne("the_one")()
```

With this message:

> E1102: RegistryOne('the_one') is not callable (not-callable)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to define a [`__init_subclass__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/#proposal) method for the base class to initialize each subclass with its own `registered` dict:

```
class BaseRegistry:
    ...

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.registered = {}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/6SaHG3

Comment: Nice. I still have an issue with Pylint `E1102: RegistryOne('the_one') is not callable (not-callable)`, though. I update the question with this information that I forget to give.

Comment: Dynamically returning a non-instance from `__new__` is an anti-pattern to begin with, one that a static code analyzer cannot deduce from statically. Use the solution in my other answer if you have to make pylint happy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason for `RegistryOne` and `RegistryTwo` to be subclasses when they really represent instances of the base class.

Make them actual instances instead:

```
class Registry:
    def __init__(self):
        self.registered = {}

    def add(self, name):
        def decorator(function):
            self.registered[name] = function
            return function
        return decorator

    def __call__(self, name):
        return self.registered[name]

RegistryOne = Registry()
RegistryTwo = Registry()
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/LPi1Du

Comment: This was one of my alternatives but I was not sure it was a good thing to instantiate an object in module A (that is at import time) that will be used in module B. Is it a common practice?

Comment: It doesn't matter what types of objects you import from a module--classes, instances, immutables, they are all objects in Python. And yes it is very common to define module-level instances for other modules to import. Take a look at all the publicly importable instances such as `AnyStr` and `Hashable` defined in the [`typing`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2c097ebdee447ded1109f99a235e65aa3533bf8/Lib/typing.py#L2564) module for example.

Comment: I link your solution but I am a bit annoyed with typing (Python 3.8).
I tried:
`T = TypeVar("T")`
...
```
    def add(self, name: str) -> Callable[[Type[T]], Type[T]]:
        def decorator(function: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
```
...
```
    def __call__(self, name: str) -> Type[T]:
```
But Mypy says:
`Cannot instantiate type "Type[<nothing>]"  [misc]` when I try: `the_one = RegistryOne("the_one")()`

Comment: I found this solution: `class Registry(Generic[T]):` ... `def add(self, name: str) -> Callable[[T], T]:` ... `def __call__(self, name: str) -> T:` ... `RegistryOne: Registry = Registry()` . I hope this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To continue [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831416), if you really, *really* want `RegistryOne` and `RegistryTwo` to be classes, then a metaclass can takes care of that:

```py
from functools import partial

class MetaRegistry(type):

  def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace):
    # The default thing
    instance = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)

    # This creates a class-level variable for each class
    # similar to how normal classes would create such variables for their instances.
    instance.registered = {}

    return instance

  def __call__(cls, name):
    # Instead of creating an instance of `cls` (the default),
    # we look for a registered class and return that.
    # In case you care, this violates the principle of leash astonishment.
    return cls.registered[name]

  # No @classmethod here.
  def add(cls, name, registry = None):
    if registry is None:
      return partial(cls.add, name)

    cls.registered[name] = registry
    return registry
```

You can then use it as:

```py
class RegistryOne(metaclass = MetaRegistry):
  pass
```

...or:

```py
class BaseRegistry(metaclass = MetaRegistry):
  pass

class RegistryOne(BaseRegistry):
  pass

class RegistryTwo(BaseRegistry):
  pass
```

The rest goes exactly as planned:

```py
@RegistryOne.add("the_one")
class Example1:
  ...

@RegistryOne.add("the_two")
class Example2:
  ...
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
  the_one = RegistryOne("the_one")()
  print(f"{the_one.scale_factor=}")  # the_one.scale_factor=1
    
  assert RegistryOne.registered != RegistryTwo.registered  # fine
```

Having said that, I concur with [@blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing): This is likely not what you need; consider changing the design instead.